# How to check if the sitemap contain some urls

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I am new to python and django, I am trying to fix a sitemap creator and one of the bugs that it would create an empty sitemap. Meaning the sitemap does not really have any urls in it.

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
</urlset>
```

I would like to know the best approach to check if the sitemap have an empty urlset tag or not.

Thanks

Comment: don't you have sample codes?

Comment: ops my bad I didn't notice they are not showing

Comment: I think catherine means the code you're using to produce the xml, not the output xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse xml:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

urlset = etree.fromstring(xml)
if urlset.find('url') is None:
   print("sitemap has no urls")
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely your bug is a direct consequence of a much more important bug - your django app has no urls in it!

Fix this and your sitemap bug goes away. What's the point in a site map with no site?

UPDATE

I don't completely understand how it will help, but if you want to parse xml then python's built in [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library might be what you're looking for. And there's more [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml?highlight=%28%28Tutorials%20on%20XML%20processing%20with%20Python%29%29) from the python site.

Comment: You think I would be posting this question if I don't have an app, it actually generates sitemaps with urls. either ways I would love to know how to parse an xml file with python. Thanks for the effort !

Comment: Sorry, my bad - your question wasn't completely clear - I thought you wanted your code to check for the existence of urls in the app before it runs. Which, as you point out, would be silly. Perhaps you could include the code that your using for clarification - what are you using to create the site map? In the mean time I'll add some links on parsing xml with python.